# 503: Max Client Queue and Topic Endpoint Flow Exceeded

Tags: jms, solace

Sometimes I am getting the following error:

```
503: Max Client Queue and Topic Endpoint Flow Exceeded
```

What I need to configure to prevent such issue?

Answer (score 3):

The number of "flows" is, roughly speaking, the number of endpoints to which you are subscribed. There are two types: ingress (for messages from your application into Solace) and egress (for messages from Solace into your application). You violated one of those limits. You can tell which by looking at the stack trace.

By default the limit on flows is 100. Before you increase this limit, ask yourself: are you really supposed to be subscribed to more than 100 queues/topics? If not, you may have a leak. Just as you wouldn't fix a memory leak by increasing memory, you shouldn't fix this leak by increasing the max flow. Are you forgetting to close your subscriptions? Are you using temporary queues? Despite their name, temporary queues [last for the life of the client session](https://docs.solace.com/Solace-PubSub-Messaging-APIs/Developer-Guide/Receiving-Guaranteed-Messages.htm#receiving_guaranteed_messages_1016811797_626222) unless you close them.

But if you really are supposed to be subscribed to so many endpoints, you may increase the max ingress and/or max egress. This can be done in SolAdmin by editing the Client Profile and selecting the Advanced Properties tab, or in solacectl by setting max-ingress or max-egress under configure/client-profile/message-spool (as explained [here](https://docs.solace.com/Configuring-and-Managing/Configuring-Client-Profiles.htm#Config-Max-Ingress)). (There is also [max setting per message spool](https://docs.solace.com/Configuring-and-Managing/VPN-Level-Msg-Spool-Config.htm#Configur32), but you are unlikely to have violated that.)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the "Max Egress Flows" setting in your client-profile has been exceeded. One egress flow will be used up for each endpoint that your application is binding to.

The "Max Egress Flows" setting can be located under the "Advanced Properties" tab, when you edit the client-profile.

Answer (score 0):

We hit the same issue during our load test. With mere few hundred messages we started getting 503 error. We identified the issue was in our producer topic creation. Once we added caching to topic destination object and the issue was resolved.